# How to load global (PostCSS) styles in Sapper?

Tags: svelte, sapper

When integrating [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) with Svelte, one can add the use [svelte-preprocess](https://github.com/kaisermann/svelte-preprocess) to add the following to `App.svelte`:

```
<style global>
  @tailwind base;                                                                                                                                     
  @tailwind components;                                                                                                                               
  @tailwind utilities;  
</style>
```

This will load the base styles correct.

However, moving these styles to `routes/index.svelte` or `routes/_layout.svelte` after migrating to Sapper does not function the same.

The error "end must be greater than start" is thrown by the Svelte compiler.

Answer (score 0):

create Tailwind.svelte

then add

```
    <style global>
  @tailwind base;                                                                                                                                     
  @tailwind components;                                                                                                                               
  @tailwind utilities;  
</style>
```

import Tailwind.svelte  to _layout.svelte